# Passing props from parent component to child components

Tags: reactjs

HI am trying to pass some data to my child component (actually data from data base). In my parent component when i console.log it i can see my data but i want to display this in my child component
and it gives me an error any suggestions pls? Here is my code

This is not the complete code for parent but i think this is what you need to see

MY parent component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './Inscription.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Adherents from "./Adherents";

function Inscription (){
   
   const [Nom, setNom] = useState("");
   const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
   const [Profession, setProfession] = useState("");
   const [Date_naiss, setDate_naiss] = useState(0);
   const [Tel, setTel] = useState(0);
   const [Date_adhession, setDate_adhession] = useState(0);
   const [formData, setformData] = useState("")

   const [Info,getInfo] = useState([])
  
   
   const addAdherent = () =>{

      Axios.post('http://localhost:3005/create',{
        Nom: Nom,
        Email: Email,
        Profession: Profession,
        Date_naiss: Date_naiss,
        Tel: Tel,
        Date_adhession: Date_adhession,
        formData:formData,

      }).then(()=>{
        console.log("success");
      })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getAllInfo();
    }, []);


    const getAllInfo = (props) =>{
       Axios.get('http://localhost:3005/adherents')
       .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
         getInfo(response.data)
       })
       .catch(error => console.log("error"))

    }

    return(
        

        <div className= "Inscription">
          <Adherents data={Info}/>  
        </div>
```

My index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: 'obincharity',
  database: 'adherents_system',
  port: '3306',

});


app.get('/adherents', (req,res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM new_table", (err, result) => {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
    
app.listen(3005, () =>{
  console.log("server working");
  });
```

My child component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Adherents(props) {
    const getAllInfo  = ()=>{
        const {menu,data} = props;
        if(data.length > 0){
            return(
                data.map((data, index) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                   
                   return(
                    <div className = "Data" key={data.Nom}>
                    <h3 className = "MainName"> {data.Nom} </h3>
                    <h4 className = "MainTel"> {data.Telephone} </h4>
                    <h4 className = "MainEmail"> {data.Email} </h4>
                    <span className="Info_fadeOut"></span>
                    </div>
                   )
                })
                
            )
        }else{
            return(<h3>No notes yet</h3>)
        }
    }
    return(
         
        <>
           {getAllInfo (props)}
        </>
    )
    }
```

this is the error it shows in my browser

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
getAllInfo
C:/Users/HP/Documents/Mutcav/client/src/Adherents.js:6
  3 | export default function Adherents(props) {
  4 |     const getAllInfo  = ()=>{
  5 |         const {menu,data} = props;
> 6 |         if(data.length > 0){
  7 |             return(
  8 |                 data.map((data, index) =>{
  9 |                     console.log(props);
View compiled
Adherents
C:/Users/HP/Documents/Mutcav/client/src/Adherents.js:28
  25 | }
  26 | return(
  27 |      
> 28 |     <>
     | ^  29 |        {getAllInfo (props)}
  30 |     </>
  31 | )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is initially no `data` is there. Try below:

```
if(Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0){
     ....
}
```

Comment: @Obin Charity, check this. this should solve the issue

Comment: thanks the error went away but nothing was passed to the child component the aim is to see my info in my child component

Comment: @ObinCharity, that means either `data` isn't an `JSON` or `data` is empty array `[ ]`. Can you check that as well?

Comment: @ObinCharity, check  `console.log(data);`

Comment: @ObinCharity, can you please mark this as the answer? since it solved your error

Answer (score 0):

in child component instead of:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Adherents({menu, data}) {
    const getAllInfo  = ()=>{
        if(data.length > 0){
            return(
                data.map((data, index) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                   
                   return(
                    <div className = "Data" key={data.Nom}>
                    <h3 className = "MainName"> {data.Nom} </h3>
                    <h4 className = "MainTel"> {data.Telephone} </h4>
                    <h4 className = "MainEmail"> {data.Email} </h4>
                    <span className="Info_fadeOut"></span>
                    </div>
                   )
                })
                
            )
        }else{
            return(<h3>No notes yet</h3>)
        }
    }
    return(
         
        <>
           {getAllInfo (props)}
        </>
    )
    }
```

try:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Adherents(props) {
    const getAllInfo  = ()=>{
        const {menu,data} = props;
        if(data.length > 0){
            return(
                data.map((data, index) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                   
                   return(
                    <div className = "Data" key={data.Nom}>
                    <h3 className = "MainName"> {data.Nom} </h3>
                    <h4 className = "MainTel"> {data.Telephone} </h4>
                    <h4 className = "MainEmail"> {data.Email} </h4>
                    <span className="Info_fadeOut"></span>
                    </div>
                   )
                })
                
            )
        }else{
            return(<h3>No notes yet</h3>)
        }
    }
    return(
         
        <>
           {getAllInfo (props)}
        </>
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining. `if(data?.length > 0)`

Try this

```
if(data?.length > 0){
  return(
    data.map((data, index) =>{
      console.log(data);
                   
      return(
        <div className = "Data" key={data.Nom}>
          <h3 className = "MainName"> {data.Nom} </h3>
          <h4 className = "MainTel"> {data.Telephone} </h4>
          <h4 className = "MainEmail"> {data.Email} </h4>
          <span className="Info_fadeOut"></span>
        </div>
      )
    })              
  )
} else {
  return(<h3>No notes yet</h3>)
}
```